# Java declared type parameter only string

Tags: java, generics

I have a class which is supposed to work by definition only with a String parameter.

So I thought about using

```
class MyClass<T extends String>
```

But then the compiler gives a warning that string is final and I can't extend it

Tried then with

```
class MyClass<String>
```

And got a warning because the parameter String is hiding class String.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Do you really need a *generic* type here?

Comment: Good question :) and now my problem is solved. I'll edit my post to explain

Comment: In your second example, you are creating a type parameter with the name `String`. You are *not* creating a type parameter which is limited to `String`s. In fact, the type parameter in your second example could have any value.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Define a ctor or method that takes a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the enlightening comment: "do you really need generics"?

I reviewed my code and found the problem. I wanted to use a type parameter because I'm implementing an interface with one

```
interface MyInterface<T>
```

and for some reason I thought I need the type paramter in the implementing class, like:

```
class MyClass<String> implements MyInterface<T>
```

But that doesn't make sense. What I needed to do is:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface<String>
```

Solved :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you don't need generics at all. You shouldn't overcomplicate your code if you don't need to. If your class is supposed to work only with String parameters, just omit the *generic* part.

So, instead of:

```
class MyClass<T extends String> {
  T myMethod() {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Just do:

```
class MyClass {
  String myMethod() {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```